# Is there a better tool than permcalc to analyse permissions?

Tags: c#, code-access-security

I have some code which needs to run under medium trust but doesn't.  I've used permcalc in the  past but it is rather painful to get the output and compare it to the medium trust definition.    What I would really like is a tool which does the analysis for me and just outputs a list of things I need to address.  Does such a tool exist? I have seen reference to a calculate permission tool in visual studio but I can't find it anywhere in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Well the reality is that PermCalc is really not good at calculating what an application really needs and it tends to assign to many privileges.

That said, PermCalc should be able to give you some indications of what your code has that needs security permissions. Can you share more details about what those are? (btw, how are you using PermCalc? on VS2008 or command line?)

Also, do you have a strategy for handling the cases where you app has functionality that requires more privileges than the ones assigned by CAS Medium Trust?